# How do I use Javascript to find the baseurl, add some other parts of a url and open in a new page?

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript

I'm using Joomla 3 and want to use Javascript to find the base url of the page, extend this url with some other bits and send a variable through the url. Then open this page in the same window.

Specifically if the base url is 'www.webpage.com', I would like to add '\index.php\animals' and then a variable '?delete=true'.

So far my code looks like this:

```
var urlRedirect = location.host + '/index.php/animals?delete=true';
window.open(urlRedirect,"_self",false);
```

If I use an alert to view urlRedirect I can see the entire url I would expect eg www.webpage.com/index.php/animals?delete=true but the page is not opening where I want. It is just going to be the base url, I suspect the default page if a weird url is entered.

What code should I use to do this?

Comment: This question should ideally asked on stackoverflow, imho.

Comment: When you type `www.webpage.com/index.php/animals?delete=true` into your address bar and then go there, does it do what you expected?

Comment: @Nagarjun, sorry I should have made clear I am using Joomla 3 in case there is a special way of doing this with Joomla.

Comment: @moomoochoo, I've just realised there was a typo in my question which I've amended. But yes www.webpage.com/index.php/animals?delete=true takes me to exactly the page I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. In Joomla I don't need to add the host. The below does what I need.

```
window.open('animals?delete=true',"_self",false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to get the host name

```
window.location.host
```

And to open the url in same tab/page, use either

```
window.location.href = window.location.host + '/index.php/animals/?delete=true';
```

or

```
window.open(window.location.host + '/index.php/animals/?delete=true','_self');
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is still not working for me. The redirect takes me to www.webpage.com/index.php, which I think is the default page it takes you to if it doesn't understand the url. Also note I had a typo in the question, the end bit has been amended to be /animals?delete=true.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following:

```
window.location.href = '/path';
```

Comment: A good answer should contain some kind of explanation.